# Why excel sheet not opening?

Tags: excel, ms-office, xlsx

I have one excel sheet but it's not opening, it showing one error message that the file extension is corrupt.

[image]

Please kindly go through the screen shots and suggest me some solution

Comment: My guess is that the file is corrupt and/or the extension doesn't match the file type.

Comment: if it is corrupt then i'll die..

Comment: Try decompressing the file - xlsx format contains zipped xml files.

Comment: can you please help me out , how do i do the decompressing thing.

Answer (score 0):

This indeed means the file is corrupted. You still have some hope to open the file. If you have LibreOffice installed, this has worked for me in the past (then just export it as a doc and try opening it again). If you don't have it, you can also try uploading it to google documents and seeing if you can rescue the file that way.

Comment: Thanks i'll download now LibreOffice and let me try

Answer (score 0):

Your file must be corrupt. It happens when not downloaded completely or uncomplete transfer of data.